# DevExpress Column Filtering Ignores Values on GridViewList

Tags: c#, vb.net, devexpress

My main issue is that in my gridviewlist when I filter a column  I get the wrong value from my code behind compared to when I don't use a filter. I've found out what causes this error but I'm not sure why.
When I filter and select a value , that value is not stored in my db and therefore it never reaches my code.
When I don't filter and select a value , that value is normally stored in my db as expected and further used by my method to give the correct outcome.

Any ideas?

P.S.: I Don't have 10 reputation and for that I'm only able to post link-images

Not Filtered UI

## [image: [Not Filtered UI]]

Not Filtered SQL
[image: Not Filtered SQL]===========================================================================

[image]===========================================================================

[image]===========================================================================

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've figured out why this issue occurs. 
While the code behind retrieved the value using DevExpress commands ( i.e gridviewlist.getrowcellvalue(rowhandle , column) duing fitlering it seemed that the rowhandle was wrong .
That could mean that when all rows are visible in a gridview , rowhandle picks up the correct row index. But when filtering it seems that somehow the row index was incorrect. As it was trying to adjust with the temporary removal of rows (filtering) but failed miserably .